# django-rest-auth with Google: How to post access token properly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, retrofit2, django-rest-auth

I'm really new to using `retrofit2`. I'm trying to send access token to the backend from mobile app and authenticate the user via Google but I can not do it properly. The backend returns 400.
My code is like this.

`views.py`

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView


class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
```

`urls.py`

```
path('rest-auth/google/', GoogleLogin.as_view()),
```

And my Java code (I'm using `retrofit2`)

```
public interface ApiService {
    // login
    @POST("/rest-auth/google/")
    Call<String> login(@Header("access_token") String accessToken);
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
    private void login() {
    ApiService service = ApiClient.getService();

    service.login(mAuthToken).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Code:" + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            mTextViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

`mAuthToken` is access token. I think I'm wrong with the way to pass the access token to backend. I might be wrong with `retrofit2` part. What am I wrong with this?

## Update

I found a thing. The access token I get in Android and the access token I get when I login via website is apparently different. I deleted the user and input the access token in the html form manually, the request is accepted.

So I guess there is a problem with access token I get in Android but I have no idea how I can fix this.

Comment: Did you try with REST API testing tools like Postman? Try the same URL with Postman and [edit] the question, post the screenshot here. My guess is that just remove `/` from starting of `@POST("/rest-auth/google/")` and add `/` to the end of BASE URL.

Comment: @Shashanth base url is `http://10.0.2.2:8000/`. And `GET` method does work. I think there is no problem with url setting. Anyway I will try it with it.

Comment: GET method works okay fine. Now you're trying with POST request and final URL will be like this `http://10.0.2.2:8000//rest-auth/google/`. Notice `//` after 8000 which causes 400 Bad Gateway error. So, just follow my previous suggestion. Remove `/` from `@POST("rest-auth/google/")`

Comment: @Shashanth I did but the same error code (400). I will try it with postman.

Comment: @Shashanth I have a question. Do I need to add something on `allauth` setting when I want to authenticate with users from mobile app?

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not much aware of Django framework and its authentication procedure.

Comment: @Ooto can you please let me know how can I access my google oauth access token?